# Jquery mobile website not working perfectly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I have made a website in jquerymobile using asp.net mvc3. this site is working fine on desktop but not working properly in mobile phones.

here is url of login page of my website. it is not working perfectly in android phone
http://partypack.co.il/

but here is design page, which is not dynamic, but it is working perfectly
http://partypack.co.il/wiseevent/login.html

Can any one please tell why this is happening ?
thanx in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on jquery mobile and made mobile site on MVC3,
you need to add these two files

```
jquery.mobile.structure.min.css

jqmfb.min.css
```